# jq array of hashes to csv

Tags: json, linux, csv, jq

So I have a data source like this:

```
{
  "things": [
    {
      "thing_name": "Bestco",
      "thing_id": 1
    },
    {
      "thing_name": "GreatCo",
      "thing_id": 2
    },
    {
      "thing_name": "DressCo",
      "thing_id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get output like this:

```
$ echo '{"things":[{"thing_name":"Bestco","thing_id":1},{"thing_name":"GreatCo","thing_id":2},{"thing_name":"DressCo","thing_id":3}]}' |
  jq -r '.things | map(.thing_name, .thing_id, "\n") | @csv' |
  sed -e 's/,"$//g' -e 's/^",//g' -e 's/^"$//g'
"Bestco",1
"GreatCo",2
"DressCo",3

$
```

Using a fake parameter seems like a hack and then needs to be clean up by sed to work. How do I do this with just jq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to put literal newlines in your data, split the data into separate arrays (one per line of desired output), and pass each one to `@csv`.

```
s='{"things":[{"thing_name":"Bestco","thing_id":1},{"thing_name":"GreatCo","thing_id":2},{"thing_name":"DressCo","thing_id":3}]}'

jq -r '.things[] | [.thing_name, .thing_id] | @csv' <<<"$s"
```

...properly emits:

```
"Bestco",1
"GreatCo",2
"DressCo",3
```